# How to Convert Array into int in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Lets say I have a array defined in Groovy like this

```
def int[] a = [1,9]
```

Now I want to convert this array into a `int` variable say `a1` such that `a1` has the value as **19**(which are the array values in the `a`) any way to do this?

Comment: I don't know groovy, but how do you store '09' in an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) you don't need the def:

```
int[] a = [0,9]
```

2) What do you mean by `09`?  Isn't that `9`?  How are you seeing this encoding working?

If you mean you just want to concatenate the numbers together, so;

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] == 1234
```

Then you could do something like:

```
int b = a.collect { "$it" }.join( '' ) as int
```

which converts each element into a string, joins them all together, and then parses the resultant String into an int

Comment: ya that value is 9 only, just to show both value should be from the array should be placed into the variable. Say if int[] a = [1,9] then i need to get as 19.

Comment: this seems easy to read and also self explanation :) thank you once again :)

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0) { a, h -> a * 10 + h }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def sb = new StringBuilder()
[0,9].each{
    sb.append(it)
}
assert sb.toString() == "09"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments on other answers, this should get you going:

```
def a = [ 0, 9, 2 ]

int a1 = a.join('') as int​

assert a1 == 92
```

As you can see from the other answers, there's many ways to accomplish what you want. Just use the one that best fit your coding style.

Comment: Thank you:) was same as tim_yates :)

Comment: Yes, I see now. But you don't need the collect method call.

Comment: I believe you do if `a` is an `int[]` as in the original question ;-)

Comment: No you don't. You can see it working here: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/443002

Comment: That doesn't have `a` as an `int[]`, that has `def a = [ 0, 9, 2 ]`, so `a` is a `List`

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're totally right. I missed this important point. You can also cast the `int[]` as a `List`, like this: `(a as List).join('') as int`. Anyway, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You already have plenty of options, but just to add to the confusion, here's another one:

```
int[] a = [1,9]
Integer number = a.toList().join().toInteger()

// test it
assert number == 19
```